# Why is there a `%` in output when I do not add `\n` in the printf statement?

Tags: c, printf

I write a C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("a\n");
}
```

And execute it, get this:

```
a
```

But if I do not add the `\n` in the printf statement then I will get this:

```
a%
```

Why?

Updated: Here are their images:

[image: First case and second case]

Comment: The code you provide is not enough to reproduce the issue. Only a is displayed.

Comment: Is `%` your prompt string?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I think different command-line will give different prompt, your command-line does not give any prompt but mine does.

Comment: @Mat What is prompt string?

Comment: Do this: `./test > /tmp/output.txt` Now what is the content of `/tmp/output.txt`?

Comment: @KerrekSB They are all just `a`, I do not find any newline when I use `less` to read the `/tmp/output.txt`. However, it does not matter again while Inspired have answered it very well. Thanks everyone anyway!

Comment: for text output you should always end with "\n", not doing so is just not nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%` character is most probably your command-line prompt.

`'\n'` is a new-line character. Possibly in the first case you see `%` at the next line, right after `a`, something like:

```
// printf("a");
% gcc prog.c
% ./a.out
a%
 ^

// printf("a\n");
% gcc prog.c
% ./a.out
a
%
^
```

EDIT: It turned out that some shells print special characters (e.g. `%`) at the end of partial output lines to preserve them from being covered with the prompt. More details at https://superuser.com/questions/645599/why-is-a-percent-sign-appearing-before-each-prompt-on-zsh-in-windows

Comment: No, there is not any `%` in the first case. It looks like different shell will give different prompt, right? By the way, my shell is Zsh.

Comment: Right. The point is that `%` is printed by shell, not by your program. And the shell prints it *always* when it is ready for the next command, so the input caret stays next to the prompt. Please take a look: is there any prompt in the first case (with `\n`) after the program terminates? And do you see any *other* prompt after `a%` ?

Comment: Actually I am afraid that there is a new line in the second case, look at the new image in the question please.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. The `%` is definitely printed out by the shell. But it seems that it's a bit more complicated: your shell tries to preserve partial line of output. Please look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/645599/why-is-a-percent-sign-appearing-before-each-prompt-on-zsh-in-windows

Answer (score 4):

The `%` is the prompt printed by your shell. It is printed when the program terminates. When there's no `\n`, there is no newline to separate the output of the `printf()` and the prompt.

Answer (score 3):

This is the prompt of your shell. Since there's no final newline, the output of your program runs straight into the next prompt.